# jQuery Dialog: Umlaut in Buttons

Tags: jquery, dialog

Thats my code:

```
 $("#contactDeleteDialog").dialog({
       title: "L&ouml;schen",
                bgiframe: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                resizable:false,
                height: 150,
                modal: true,
                buttons:{
                    Löschen:function(){
                       //do something
                    },
                    Abbrechen:function(){
                      //do something else
                    }
                }
    })
```

The Title is string so i can use ö for ö. but how can i do it for the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
"Löschen": function(){
    //do something
},
```

Answer (score 3):

Enclose it in quotes:

```
buttons: {
    'Löschen': function() { ... }
}
```